# SSRS- Parameters to filter out line graph

Tags: reporting-services

I need help with filtering out datasets with parameters. So I would like to show specific datasets when a user chooses from a list. So lets say we have 3 datasets (Good Units, Streaks and Voids) I want the user to be able to select one or more of these choices and present it in a line graph.

Is its possible to display datasets that are selected? If its not possible to show multiple datasets then one is fine.

Comment: If possible, combine all your data on the server into a single dataset, this will make it simple to filter within the report. Without knowing more about your database(s) then I can't offer more help.

Comment: Sorry I made an error when I wrote my question. I have one data set and its like this: Dataset1: { Good Units, Streaks, Voids, Number Accepted, etc}. I want to be able to select any entity in this data set with a parameter. Is it possible?